# Displaying new link after login [REACT]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session, authentication

I am creating login form in REACT. The email/password are checked versus database record and if login successful I want to store session and display link to extra component in the header. I got this to work however after every login/logout I need to refresh the browser manually to display the extra link. Can anyone point me to what I am doing wrong ?

Login.js

```
 fetch('http://localhost:5000/getUsers')
            .then((data) => data.json())
            .then((data) => {
                // console.log(data);
                return data.filter(user => (user.EMAIL === email && user.PASSWORD === password));
            })
            .then((data) => {
                if (data.length === 1) {
                    localStorage.setItem('user', data[0].EMAIL);
                    localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn',true);
                    this.setState({email:data[0].EMAIL, password: data[0].PASSWORD, isLoggedIn: true })
```

In my routing

```
const routing = (
  <Router>
    <div>
        <Header name={localStorage.getItem("user")}  />
```

In the Header component

```
this.state = {
            name : this.props.name
        }

{(this.state.name !== "") ?
                    <li> <a href="/updateLiveGames">Update Live Games</a></li>
                    :
                    ""
                }
```

This works but I need to refresh browser (F5).

Thanks for any help.

I expect to login user and display extra link in my header only when user logged in.

Answer (score 1):

In the Header component
Don't set state, use props.name like this:

```
{(this.props.name !== "")
  ? <li> <a href="/updateLiveGames">Update Live Games</a></li>
  : ""
}
```

When you initialize this.state in header component, it will be set just once on component construction. That's why you should use this.props which will be refreshed on every component update.

In routing when you use localStorage.getItem("user") it doesn't force refresh, because it isn't neither state nor props property, thus it doesn't refresh the component.

As you don't use Redux, you should pass a callback as prop from Login.js to routing:

```
.then((data) => {
  if (data.length === 1) {
  localStorage.setItem('user', data[0].EMAIL);
  localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn',true);
  this.props.setLoginData(data[0].EMAIL)
```

And in routing you should get it:

```
<Login setLoginData={this.setLoginData} />

setLoginData = (name) => {
  this.setState({name});
}
```

And pass this.state.name to Header component:

```
<Header name={this.state.name}  />
```